# why Redirect code in php work automatically?

Tags: php, html, authentication, header

I want to write some code to login users and when the user didn't register already in database send him to "register.php" page. I used header('Location: register.php') code for this but when i refresh the page without any click to register button it goes automatically to that page and login form didn't show up!

here is my "login.php" code:

```
<?php

require 'core_inc.php';
require 'connect_inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['txtusername']) && isset($_POST['txtpassword']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['txtusername']) && !empty($_POST['txtpassword']))
    {               
    $username = trim($_POST['txtusername']);
    $password = trim($_POST['txtpassword']);
    $hash_passwword = md5($password);

    $query = "select `id` from `for_login` where `username` = '$username' and `password` = '$hash_passwword'";          
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
    {                   
        $query_num_rows =  mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($query_num_rows == 0){
            echo 'invalid username or password! if you have not registered yet please do it!';
        }
        else if($query_num_rows == 1)               
            {   
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
    }
}
else 'please fill the blanks';  
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="<?php  echo $current_file; ?>" method="post">
    please enter your username and password to login. if you already not         registered please click to register button! :) <br><br>
username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="txtusername"><br>
    password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="txtpassword"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="login">   
    <input type="submit" value="register" onClick="<?php header('Location:     register.php'); ?>" name="btnregister"  >    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and "core_inc.php" is here:

```
<?php

 @session_start();
 $current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
 $http_referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>
```

And i know that there is no problem with "connect_inc.php" , it connect successfully to database. and i tried to remove other irrelevant codes like "" but it didn't help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this...

`<a href="register.php">Register</a>` instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="register" onClick="<?php header('Location:     register.php'); ?>" name="btnregister">`
```

Comment: i used your code but the problem still there! it seems problem is not up to "header..." . I'm confused

Comment: `"select * from for_login where username = '$username' and password = '$hash_passwword' ";` ...You don't need to use ` ...

Comment: I need to check the entered valued with the values in database, why i don't need to it?

Comment: ok , but i don't know what to do about this problem! thank you

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` requires a javascript function, not PHP. Try

`window.location='register.php'`

So in this case:

`<input type="submit" value="register" onClick="window.location='register.php'" name="btnregister">`

Answer (score 0):

remove the onclick function completely from the submit field, add

```
header('Location:register.php');
```

to your

```
    if($query_num_rows == 0){
    echo 'invalid username or password! if you have not registered yet please do it!';
    header('Location:register.php');
    }
```